# Angular2 - reuse component with different services/providers

Tags: angular, service, components

I am developing an app which has Restful API for backend and Angular2 for frontend.

I want to have two graphs in a view. Say, one graph is of employee-attendance and other is of product-sales. One API for each is available for fetching data from server.

How should I plan it?

Should I be having two components one employee-attendance and one product-sales, which in-turn will use their own services and fetch data and populate the component?

OR

Should I have only one component as 'graph'? In this case how to fetch data? Is there any mechanism / good-practices about services to achieve this?

Tried searching online by couldn't get any relevant guidelines.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I would of implemented it, a more of a OOP way.

Services:

```
export interface IGraphServices {
  getGraphData(): string;
}

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeAttendanceService implements IGraphServices {
  getGraphData(): string {
    return "Employee Attendance Data";
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class ProductSalesService implements IGraphServices {
  getGraphData(): string {
    return "Product Sales Data";
  }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'graph',
  template: '<div>Graph component</div>'
})
export class GraphComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('service') service: number;

  constructor(@Inject('IGraphServices')private providerService: IGraphServices[]) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.providerService[this.service].getGraphData());
  }
}
```

In your NgModule providers:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'IGraphServices', useClass: EmployeeAttendanceService, multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: 'IGraphServices', useClass: ProductSalesService, multi: true
    }
]
```

Usage:

```
<!-- EmployeeAttendanceService -->
<graph [service]="0"></graph>

<!-- ProductSalesService -->
<graph [service]="1"></graph>
```

Comment: This seems to be a better way. Less repetition, more compact, and more modular. I will adopt this style in my app. Thanks a ton 12seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a good idea to build two different or a single component is difficult to answer with the information you provided.

You can

- inject the service in the parent and pass it to an input of the graph component.
- inject both services into the graph component and pass a parameter to an input that tells the graph component which service to use
- create one service that provides methods for employee-attendance and product-sales data and use an input in the graph component to tell it what method it should use.
- use a parent component that has the provider registered that you want the graph component to use. When the graph component injects the service it gets the one provided by the parent.

```
@Component({
  input: 'my-graph',
  template: ' show the graph here '
})
class MyGraphComponent {
  @Input() data;
}
```

```
@Component({
  input: 'employee-attendance-graph',
  template: '<my-graph [data]="data"></my-graph>'
})
class EmployeeAttendanceGraph {
  constructor(private data:Service1) {}
}
```

```
@Component({
  input: 'product-sales-graph',
  template: '<my-graph [data]="data"></my-graph>'
})
class ProductSalesGraph {
  constructor(private data:Service2) {}
}
```

Then use it like

```
<employee-attendance-graph></employee-attendance-graph>
<product-sales-graph></product-sales-graph>
```

Comment: The components will have similar GUI and Controls (Type-of-Graph, Start-Date, End-Date and Legend). To avoid repetition, I am trying to have only one component and I want to inject data from different services based on the intended usage. My question is how to achieve this?

I like your second suggestion, but not much, as it is asking to change back-end. We would like to avoid changes to backend as much as possible. Is there any way of passing a token to the components from the front-end's side by which the component uses desired service.

Thanks Gunter.

Comment: I would create 3 components. One that shows the graph, and one for each graph type where you add the graph component to the view. In `<employee-attendanc-graph>` you inject service1 and pass it to the nested graph component using an input binding and in `<product-sales-graph>` you inject service2 and pass this to the nested graph using the input.

Comment: Gunter, may be fourth option is good. Can you shed some more light on to how to do it. OR if you can point me to any tutorial that guides how to get this done, will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. Thank for putting it up nicely. I think this answers my query.  

I will mark this as done. But if someone else feels/know some better way to do it, please share.

Thanks you very much Gunter.